# Series Stubs and Microstrip Technology

Tags: rf, integrated-circuit, power-electronics, transmission-line, microstrip

Why are series stubs difficult to realize in microstrip technology?

I read this statement in some text about the realization of microstrip filters, in which the solution for this problem is that of realizing them through parallel stubs related to the series ones by kuroda identities.

With Series Stub I mean a series short circuited stub, connected as in the [following picture (C)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/9/97/Commensurate_line_theory.svg/440px-Commensurate_line_theory.svg.png)

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I added an image to clarify what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need 2 pieces of transmission line which have  both lines freely connectable, total 4 wires freely connectable. Unfortunately microstrips have the other wire stucked to the groundplane. You have no way to suddenly rotate the electric field 90 degrees. In MS the E-field is between a wire and the groundplane, in stubs it should be between the wires. In theory this might work if the stubs are verical, perpendicular to the groundplane. But then they aren't microstrip.

Comment: Ok, so if I have correctly understood, the problem is that microstrips have only a wire and a GND plane. But what does it happen if I implement a series stub by using anyway a microstrip (by using its wire and its ground plane as if they were two wires)?

Comment: Its a stub. But if your main circuit is in XY plane with z thickness only for the insulation layer, your stub must be built to z direction and it must have its ground in XZ or YZ plane. I guess it's not easy to make the branching so that the wave jumps to your stub properly. The whole problem is absurd, because all possible reactances can be made in a simpler way.

Comment: Perfect, it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

In other words ...

- the single-end lumped element filter must be transformed into a symmetric differential stripline, using 1/8th waves (x2) as a 1/4 wave
- composed of series-impedances shared by each element with shorted stub impedances to simulate either a capacitor or an inductor
- but are now in a mirror image differential pair

  - such that it can be mirrored on a ground plane as a single-ended stripline ( as shown in your sequenced picture ABCDE)

E.g. 5th Order Low Pass Filter with equiv lumped circuit as ;
- 50 Ohm stripline source driving shunt C,series L, shunt C, series L shunt C and back to 50 Ohm stripline.
- or a CLCLC Low Pass filter

[image]

The impedances of the stripline are over a suitable dielectric and ground plane.

Answer:

A Ladder series stub single ended while the open parallel stub is  differential so not realizable as a single ended filter over a ground plane as seen in your figure C with the  return path having a differential open stub.